# Backpack Laravel issues with his and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, iis, relationship, laravel-backpack

I'm new in Laravel and i have several issues according my connection with my iis and sql server.

First of all i have 405 error on deleting from CrudTable. I suppose that this is an iis error but i'm asking here in case that someone knows how to figure this out.

The other problem that i have is that i cannot display in 1 to many relationship the value and not the id of a foreign table.

I'm getting an empty column and in create blade, i select a specific value and the system inserts a zero on that column.

Below you can see my code.

```
table book_code
{
code varchar(15) PK,
title varchar(50)
}
```

bookcodes Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Backpack\CRUD\CrudTrait;

class bookcodes extends Model
{
   use CrudTrait;

   protected $table = 'book_codes';
   protected $primaryKey = 'code';
   protected $fillable = ['title'];

   public function rest_declaration()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Models\rest_declaration');
   }
}
```

bookcodes Controller has nothing

```
table rest_declaration
{
id int,
date1 date,
date2 date,
code //the foreign of bookcodes
}
```

rest_declaration Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Backpack\CRUD\CrudTrait;
use DB;

class rest_declaration extends Model
{
   use CrudTrait;

   protected $table = 'rest_declaration';
   protected $primaryKey = 'aa'; //is my id
   protected $fillable = ['aa', 'code', 'date1', 'date2'];

   public function bookcodes()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\bookcodes');
   }
}
```

rest_declaration Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController;

// VALIDATION: change the requests to match your own file names if you need form validation
use App\Http\Requests\rest_declarationRequest as StoreRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\rest_declarationRequest as UpdateRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class rest_declarationCrudController extends CrudController
{
   public function setup()
   {
               parent::__construct();

       /*
       |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
       | BASIC CRUD INFORMATION
       |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
       */
       $this->crud->setModel('App\Models\rest_declaration');
       $this->crud->setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/restdeclaration');
       $this->crud->setEntityNameStrings('rest declaration', 'rest declaration');
       $this->crud->setDefaultPageLength(10);
       $this->crud->allowAccess('show');
       $this->crud->addClause('where', 'code', '=', Auth::user()->name );

       $this->crud->allowAccess('details_row');
       $this->crud->enableAjaxTable();
       $this->crud->enableExportButtons();

       //Fields for Create and Edit Forms
       $this->crud->addField([    // SELECT
           'label'                     => 'AA',
           'type'                      => 'text',
           'name'                      => 'aa1',
           'value'                     => $this->getmaxaa(),
           'attributes'                =>
                           ['disabled' => 'disabled',],
       ]);
       $this->crud->addField([    // SELECT
           'label'                     => 'AA',
           'type'                      => 'hidden',
           'name'                      => 'aa',
           'value'                     => $this->getmaxaa(),
       ]);

       $this->crud->addField([    // SELECT
           'label'                     => 'BookCode',
           //'type'                      => 'select',
           'name'                      => 'code',
           'entity'                    => 'bookcodes',
           'attribute'                 => 'title',
           'model'                     => 'App\Models\bookcodes',
       ]);

       $this->crud->addField([   // Date
           'name'                      => 'date1',
           'label'                     => 'From',
           'type'                      => 'date_picker',
           // optional:
           'date_picker_options'       => [
                       'todayBtn'      => false,
                       'format'        => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
                       'language'      => 'en',
                       'autoclose'     => true,
                       'showOnFocus'   => false,
           ],
       ]);

       $this->crud->addField([   // Date
           'name'                      => 'date2',
           'label'                     => 'To',
           'type'                      => 'date_picker',
           // optional:
           'date_picker_options'       => [
                       'todayBtn'      => false,
                       'format'        => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
                       'language'      => 'en',
                       'autoclose'     => true,
                       'showOnFocus'   => true,
           ],
       ]);

       $this->crud->addColumn([
           'label'                     => 'Άδεια',
           'type'                      => 'select',
           'name'                      => 'code',
           'entity'                    => 'bookcodes',
           'attribute'                 => 'title',
           'model'                     => 'App\Models\bookcodes',
       ]);

       $this->crud->addColumn([
               'name'                  => 'date1',
               'label'                 => 'From',
               'type'                  => 'date',
               'date_picker_options'   => [
               'todayBtn'              => false,
               'format'                => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
               'language'              => 'en',],
           ]);

       $this->crud->addColumn([
               'name'                  => 'date2',
               'label'                 => 'To',
               'type'                  => 'date',
               'date_picker_options'   => [
               'todayBtn'              => false,
               'format'                => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
               'language'              => 'en',],
           ]);
   }

   public function store(StoreRequest $request)
   {
       $redirect_location = parent::storeCrud($request);
       return $redirect_location;
   }

   public function update(UpdateRequest $request)
   {
       $redirect_location = parent::updateCrud($request);
       return $redirect_location;
   }

   public function getmaxaa()
   {
       $max = 'App\Models\AitisiAdeias'::max('aa');
       $max = $max + 1;
       return $max;
   }

}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Could you help me please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution according the issue with delete function.

I didn't use any Route:: etc. The problem was my iis. I created a new map inside Handler Mapping in IIS and i selected the PHP version that used for my app. Then i selected All Verbs and Script value in the third tab.

And... Voila.. Delete now is working like a charm!!

The problem with relationship still exists.
I realised that changing the following :

```
$this->crud->addColumn([
           'label'                     => 'BookCode',
           'type'                      => 'select',
           'name'                      => 'code',
           'entity'                    => 'bookcodes',
           'attribute'                 => 'title',
           'model'                     => 'App\Models\bookcodes',
       ]);
```

to

```
$this->crud->addColumn([
           'label'                     => 'BookCode',
           'type'                      => 'select2',
           'name'                      => 'code',
           'entity'                    => 'bookcodes',
           'attribute'                 => 'title',
           'model'                     => 'App\Models\bookcodes',
       ]);
```

i'm getting the code and no any more the empty column. But still i need to get the title and not the code.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

for 405 error  I think you are using  wrong route type,  Your are sending post request  but the route declared as get.try  Route::any and see if it solve the problem!

for second issue your namespace is incorrect

try 'App\rest_declaration'

Answer (score 0):

in your model you need to pass also the column for the connection

```
public function bookcodes()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\bookcodes', 'code');
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my delayed answer. I’ve already tried that with no luck. I fixed that with a function which retrieves the list from the external table but I know that this isn’t the right way. Maybe the problem is that the primary key is nvarchar and not int.